# Twilio sdk not corresponding the api

Tags: java, api, twilio

Im using the twilio java api, trying to get country pricing:

```
new CountryFetcher("US").fetch(twilioRestClient)
```

but it throws deserialization error:

```
com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Can not construct instance of com.twilio.type.InboundCallPrice$Type, problem: No enum constant com.twilio.type.InboundCallPrice.Type.TOLL FREE
at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7243145f; line: 1, column: 809] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[1])
```

is it a bug in there sdk and i should just use Rest or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using the Java library version 6 or 7? Can you share a bit more of your code around the line you have above?

Comment: Already opened an issue in their github, they said it is a bug and fixed it, will be pushed with the next release

Comment: Ah great! Thanks for opening the issue!

Answer (score 0):

opened an issue, it is a bug in the SDK and will be fixed on upcoming release

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/issues/338